# The simple MLP NN for regression in PyTorch - very slow learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, regression

after some days spent with PyTorch I ended up with the neural network, that despite being quite a good predictor, is extremely slow to learn. It is a MLP with 54 input neurons, 27 hidden neurons with sigmoid activation function, and one linear output neuron. Currently, running the NN for 1000 epochs lasts around 1 hour. I had some experience with PyTorch MLP with the same architecture, but 'created from scratch' - without bias, which was worse in terms of predictive capabilities, but the whole training lasted for less than 20s.

The reason I created new NN is that now my model is much more flexible (changing number of neutrons, number of layers or activation functions takes seconds). Also, I tried to use as many built-in tools as possible, so there was no problem with e.g. introducing bias to the neurons. What is also quite surprising is that during the learning, this NN utilizes ~10% of the CPU power, while the 'scratch-based' network used 95-100% all the time (details at the bottom).

The code is following (I skipped the imports part):

Hyperparameters:

```py
hyperparam_input_neurons = 54
hyperparam_hidden_neurons_1 = 27
hyperparam_output_neurons = 1

param_learning_rate = 0.01
param_weight_decay = 1e-6
param_momentum = 0.9
param_epochs = 2000
param_test_data_fraction=0.5

loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
```

training data:

```py
train = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
Xf = torch.tensor(train.values,dtype=torch.float)
res=pd.read_csv('output.csv')
yf=torch.tensor(res.values,dtype=torch.float)

ntrainingelems=int((len(yf)+1)*param_test_data_fraction)

Xt=Xf[:ntrainingelems]
yt=yf[:ntrainingelems]

Xv=Xf[ntrainingelems:]
yv=yf[ntrainingelems:]

traintensor = TensorDataset(Xt, yt)
validtensor = TensorDataset(Xv, yv)
trainloader = DataLoader(traintensor, batch_size=ntrainingelems, shuffle=False) 
validloader = DataLoader(validtensor, batch_size=(len(yf)-ntrainingelems), shuffle=False)
```

NN definition:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(hyperparam_input_neurons, hyperparam_hidden_neurons_1)
        self.output = nn.Linear(hyperparam_hidden_neurons_1, hyperparam_output_neurons)
  
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.hidden(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.output(x)
        return x

model = Model()
```

learning:

```py
epoch_number = []
mse_loss_t = []
mse_loss_v = []


optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=param_learning_rate, weight_decay= param_weight_decay, momentum = param_momentum, nesterov = True)

for epoch in range(1, param_epochs+1):
    train_loss, valid_loss = [], []
    epoch_number.append(int(epoch))
    
    model.train()
    for data, target in trainloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_function(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss.append(loss.item())
    mse_loss_t.append(np.mean(train_loss))

    model.eval()
    for data, target in validloader:
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_function(output, target)
        valid_loss.append(loss.item())        
    mse_loss_v.append(np.mean(valid_loss))
        
    if epoch==1 or epoch%100==0:
        print ("Epoch:", epoch, "Training Loss: ", np.mean(train_loss), "Valid Loss: ", np.mean(valid_loss))
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong here? Or how to make the learning quicker (at least 2000x)?

FYI the very quick-to-learn 'scratch-based' NN I mentioned earlier used different definition of the forward method, so I guessed this may be the reason (see code below)... but if I understand the documentation correctly, the NN.linear can also make quick parallel computations.

```py
def forward(self, X):
        self.z = torch.matmul(X, self.W1)
        self.z2 = self.sigmoid(self.z)
        self.z3 = torch.matmul(self.z2, self.W2)
```

EDIT - after adding the batching to the DataLoaders, as per @Ilyas Moutawwakil tip, it works significantly faster, but it is still way slower than the 'scratch-based' NN. Any idea where the issue is located? I thought maybe the stochastic gradient method is slower than steepest descent one used in the 'scratch-based', but I haven't found any confirmation of that theory so far.

Comment: You forget to use batches of data, so your nn is learning one data point at a time.

Comment: Note that 1) your original forward is not equivalent because it has no bias term (equivalent to `nn.Linear(..., bias=False)`, 2) `nn.Linear` is going to be better optimized for this sort of thing because it likely uses `torch.bmm` (or just C++) under the hood.

Comment: @IlyasMoutawwakil - of course you are right, I did forget. Thank you for your quick and correct response.
Nonetheless, I added the batching now, and even though the learning is much quicker (it takes 6min instead of 60min), it's still way beyond the 'scratch-based' NN. Do you have any clue why? My new code:
trainloader = DataLoader(traintensor, batch_size=ntrainingelems, shuffle=False)
validloader = DataLoader(validtensor, batch_size=(len(yf)-ntrainingelems), shuffle=False)

Comment: And I forgot to mention - now, with all samples being fed at once, the CPU indeed goes for 100% all the time. But still, the 'old' NN is outperforming the above code in terms of learning time (same epochs number, architecture, etc. - no bias and more "free" scratch form rather than organized PyTorch)